# C++/WinRT: How to merge elements of a geometry group?

Tags: canvas, drawing, shapes, c++-winrt

I tried to create a shape using a GeometryGroup:

```
Canvas canvas = Canvas();
myBorder.Child(canvas);

winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Path path = winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Path();
path.StrokeThickness(1);
path.Stroke(SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black()));
path.Fill(SolidColorBrush(Colors::Yellow()));
canvas.Children().Append(path);

GeometryGroup geoGrp = GeometryGroup();
geoGrp.FillRule(FillRule::Nonzero);
path.Data(geoGrp);

float shapeHeigh = 20.0f;
float shapeWidth = 100.0f;

EllipseGeometry ellipse1 = EllipseGeometry();
ellipse1.Center({ shapeHeigh / 2.0f , shapeHeigh / 2.0f });
ellipse1.RadiusX(shapeHeigh / 2.0f);
ellipse1.RadiusY(shapeHeigh / 2.0f);
geoGrp.Children().Append(ellipse1);

EllipseGeometry ellipse2 = EllipseGeometry();
ellipse2.Center({ shapeWidth - (shapeHeigh / 2.0f), shapeHeigh / 2.0f });
ellipse2.RadiusX(shapeHeigh / 2.0f);
ellipse2.RadiusY(shapeHeigh / 2.0f);
geoGrp.Children().Append(ellipse2);

RectangleGeometry rect = RectangleGeometry();
rect.Rect(Windows::Foundation::Rect(
    shapeHeigh / 2.0f,          //X
    0.0f,                       //Y
    shapeWidth - shapeHeigh ,   //width
    shapeHeigh));               //height
geoGrp.Children().Append(rect);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The stroke is drawn around each geometry of the group.

However, I want the stroke to be drawn around the entire shape so it looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about creating a `Rectangle`, then set its `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` to half height. You just need one `Rectangle` to show the shape you need.

Comment: Ok, the point goes to you. The example was perhaps poorly chosen. But I'm more concerned with the general question of how I can unite the elements of the group. Wouldn't that be the logical purpose of such a group?